# Java classpath in VS code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

In a java project I want to compile classes using Vs code.
The project is **not** Gradle nor maven based.
The compilation requires classpath (i.e. some lib jar files).

I want to compile whichever the class I am currently working on (not all as there are 100s of classes and I do not want them to update each time). e.g.

```
$javac -cp c.jar HelloWorld.java
```

How can I set classpath in Vs code to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

YOu sould try using java.classPath https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configuration